# How do I get index of element in std::deque

Tags: c++, deque

I have a deque and I have an object that belongs to the deque.

```
std::deque<Item> items;
// full deque with objects
// ...
Item &item = items[5];
```

Now I want to get index of that element in the deque:

```
size_t index = &item - &*m_items.begin();
```

I expect index to be equal to 5, but I get something bigger than deque's size.

Of course, I can run through the deque looking for my object, but is it possible to get index of element in O(1)?

Comment: " deques are not guaranteed to store all its elements in contiguous storage locations: accessing elements in a deque by offsetting a pointer to another element causes undefined behavior." => see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/

Comment: A deque does not guarantee contiguous storage, so this is not the solution you're looking for.

Comment: You could do something about this if you had an iterator instead of just a reference...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends on there having been no reference invalidations, but you can use `std::find_if` to find the element by address, then use `std::distance` to get the index.

```
Item &item = items[5];
Item* p = &item;
auto it = std::find_if(items.begin(),
                       items.end(),
                       [p](const Item& i) {return p == &i;});

auto idx = std::distance(items.begin(), it);
```

The easier option would be to keep an iterator instead of a reference.

Answer (score 6):

You can't compute the index of an element in a `std::deque<T>` based on its address as the elements in a `std::deque<T>` are not store in contiguous memory. At best, you could use an iterator and subtract the `begin()` iterator from the location. Note, however, that adding or removing elements to a `std::deque<T>` invalidates all iterator even though pointers or references to objects are not invalidated.

Comment: The last sentence is only true for random-access adding or removing. Only the affected iterators are invalidated with adding or removing at the beginning or end (like `push_back` or `pop_back`), along with the past-the-end iterator in the latter case.